# Find all the triangles satisfying $\cos(A)\cos(B)+\sin(A)\sin(B)\sin(C)=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, triangles

I am trying to solve the problem of finding all triangles with angles $A$, $B$ and $C$ (in $[0,\pi]$) such that $\cos A\cos B+\sin A\sin B\sin C=1$.

In the case where the triangle has a right angle, it can be proved that $C=\frac{\pi}{2}$ (thus $C$ is the right angle and $A=B=\frac{\pi}{4}$. If we assume that the triangle is isosceles, then the triangle is flat or has a right angle (hence is the above solution).

My intuition says that these are the only solutions but I struggle to prove it. Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried using the [prosthaphaeresis formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosthaphaeresis#The_identities) ?

Comment: $A=B = \frac\pi 4, C = \frac \pi 2$ gives $LHS = 2$.

Comment: @Nemo: I mistyped the equation. Sorry.

Comment: @Michael You deleted your answer, but why? I think it is good. The second of your terms is nonnegative, so the only way that the total can be $1$ is if it equals $0$ (so $C=\pi/2$) and $\cos(A-B)=1$ (so $A=B-\pi/4$). This corresponds to the one solution OP has identified.

Comment: For users who cannot see deleted answers, Michael has this answer: $\cos(A)\cos(B)+\sin(A)\sin(B)\sin(C)$ is the same as $\cos(A-B)-(1-\sin(C))\sin(A)\sin(B)$. Now $(1-\sin(C))\sin(A)\sin(B)$ is nonnegative, and $\cos(A-B)$ is at most $1$. It follows that for the total to equal $1$, $\cos(A-B)=1$ and $(1-\sin(C))\sin(A)\sin(B)=0$. So $A=B$, and $C=\pi/2$. And OP's intuition is correct.

Comment: @alex.jordan: I am actually one of these people that cannot see deleted answers (how many rep points are necessary?). Thanks. If Micheal does not want to rewrite his solution, maybe you can write it so I can accept it.

Comment: @Taladris I'm not sure---maybe 10,000? Do you agree that the solution works? If so, please write it yourself and accept it. I thought it was a pretty nice observation, but it wasn't mine.